# Error propagation for the median of time-series

Tags: time-series, median, error-propagation

Let's assume that we have a set of different measurements from an instrument of a parameter of a parameter **P** that changes with time during a time period **t**. Let's also assume that the measurements follow a non-normal unspecified distribution, their are not autocorrelated  and we calculate their **median**  for the period **t**.
If each measurement has an uncertainty **u**, how can we calculate the **uncertainty** propagated to the **median** from the uncertainties **u** of the measurements?

Comment: Often when values change with time they tend to be associated with one another.  This makes it impossible to propagate uncertainty (correctly) without first analyzing the nature and degree of this association: that's the basic idea behind all time series analysis.  If you would like to make any progress, then, please tell us what you know (or assume) about such temporal associations.

Comment: Googling “standard deviation of the sample median” is a reasonable place to start